# How can I make it better with Kotlin isNullOrEMpty()

Tags: android, kotlin

```
fun updatePath(query: String?){
        this.query = query
    
    }

    fun build(): String {

        if (!query.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            val encodedQuery = encode(query)   
        }
  
    }
```

`encode()` accepts only not null String variable.
but here it still complains that query that I am passing?
I was expecting using `isNullOrEmpty()` should solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use kotlin [Scope](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html) function with [Null Safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) to avoid such warnings.

Like this -

```
fun build(): String {
    query?.let {
        if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
            val encodedQuery = encode(query)
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Thanks @Tenfour04 for notifying this, we should used instance inside block.

```
fun build(): String {
    query?.let { it ->
        if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
            val encodedQuery = encode(**it**)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This still won't work because `query` is nullable. You would need `encode(it)`.

Comment: Thanks @Tenfour04 I totally missed that. Didn't used context object inside.

Answer (score 1):

I would use smartcast or possibly `takeIf` to avoid nesting.

```
query?.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }?.let {
    encode(it)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `encode` accepts any non-null string (including empty string), then you could do the following.

```
fun build(): String {
  ...
  val encodedQuery = query?.let(::encode)
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for the compiler to smartcast, as your query is a `var`, therefore it might change. You could do the following:
`val query = query`
Before the `if`

This shadows the name query. You can still use the query property through `this.query`